# Redirect gestures to another widget

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for a way to redirect gestures(touches) from one widget to another. The use case for this is that I need to show a transparent screen(bottom sheet) above another screen(map) using `Navigator` and redirect gestures from that transparent screen to the one below.

Unfortunately `Navigator` route absorbs all gestures at the root level, thus they cannot pass-through. I'm also unable to use `IgnorePointer` because there are interactive elements in the transparent screen.

Is there a way to do this?

p.s. I'm aware that `OverlayEntry` solves this, but I'm looking for a way to achieve this using `Navigator`

Comment: most likely you are using [ModalRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute-class.html) - the docs say: *"A route that blocks interaction with previous routes.

ModalRoutes cover the entire Navigator. "*

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Looks like the only option is to create a custom route based on TransitionRoute

Comment: thats right, or `OverlayRoute` if you dont need transitions